# How to fill <select> with options using PHP and SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, forum

My question is: I want to show all SQL answers from a specific table inside the `<select>` using php.

I have tried to get it working, but without much success as it only shows one result.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include 'connect.php';
include 'header.php';
set_time_limit(10);


$cat = $bdd->query('SELECT cat_id,cat_name,cat_description FROM categories');
$categories_list = $cat->fetch();


While ($categories_list = $cat->fetch()) {
$cat_name = $categories_list['cat_name'];
}


$cat->closeCursor();

echo '<form method="post" action="accès/create_topic_post.php">';
echo '<label for="sujet">Sujet :';
echo '<input type="text" name="sujet" id="sujet" required autofocus>';
echo '</label>';
echo '<label for="cat">Catégories :';
echo '<select name="topic_name">';
echo "<option value=\"".$cat_name."\" >$cat_name </option>";
echo '</select>';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Envoyer">';
echo '</form>';

?>
```

Comment: You have to use loop for this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to loop over results manually, as PDO has a function that can do it for you already, called [fetchAll()](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#column). You have to use it instead of fetch() if you want to get an array of rows.

However, beside it, you need to learn PHP and programming in general. Because your current code makes little sense. To output an array, you have to use a **loop:**

```
$cat = $bdd->query('SELECT cat_name FROM categories');
$categories_list = $cat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN); // here it is

echo '<form method="post" action="accès/create_topic_post.php">';
echo '<label for="sujet">Sujet :';
echo '<input type="text" name="sujet" id="sujet" required autofocus>';
echo '</label>';
echo '<label for="cat">Catégories :';
echo '<select name="topic_name">';
foreach ($categories_list as $cat_name)
{ 
    echo "<option value='$cat_name'>$cat_name</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Envoyer">';
echo '</form>';
```

Comment: Better but, it out just some `int`

Comment: Oh yeah. I blindly copy-pasted your query. It is fixed now

Comment: Thanks so mutch :D

Answer (score 2):

That's totally not the way to do it. Have a separation between PHP and HTML. And make sure you have the `option` echoed out inside the loop. Something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="accès/create_topic_post.php">
  <label for="sujet">Sujet :
    <input type="text" name="sujet" id="sujet" required autofocus>
  </label>
  <label for="cat">Catégories :
    <select name="topic_name">
    <?php
    // Loop it here.
    while ($categories_list = $cat->fetch()) {
        $cat_name = $categories_list['cat_name'];
        echo "<option value=\"".$cat_name."\" >$cat_name </option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>
  </label><!-- You forgot this -->
  <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" />
</form>
```

Comment: Some people wanna watch the world burn with your downvotes right? What's the reason?

Comment: I see no obvious reason for a DV on this answer

Comment: @RiggsFolly True, as I said, "some people wanna watch the world burn". LoL.

Comment: You are right, DV without sharing reason or improvement, bad approach

Answer (score 2):

You keep replacing `cat_name` every time you read data from the SQL server. You need to store it in an array

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    include 'connect.php';
    include 'header.php';
    set_time_limit(10);


    $cat = $bdd->query('SELECT cat_id,cat_name,cat_description FROM categories');
    //$categories_list = $cat->fetch(); This line discards a row of data


    $cat_names = array();   //array for category names
    While ($categories_list = $cat->fetch()) {
        //Add newest 'cat_name' to the array
        $cat_names[] = $categories_list['cat_name'];
    }


    $cat->closeCursor();

    echo '<form method="post" action="accès/create_topic_post.php">';
    echo '<label for="sujet">Sujet :';
    echo '<input type="text" name="sujet" id="sujet" required autofocus>';
    echo '</label>';
    echo '<label for="cat">Catégories :';
    echo '<select name="topic_name">';
    //Loop and read back each category name
    foreach ($cat_names as $cat_name){
        echo "<option value=\"".$cat_name."\" >$cat_name </option>";
    }
    echo '</select>';
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Envoyer">';
    echo '</form>';

?>
```

Comment: This is the best answer out of the ones posted so far. Seeing as it's the only one that clearly separates concerns, between the business logic and the generation of the output. Only things I'd change is to remove the `closeCursor()` call, as it's not needed in this example, and use `htmlspecialchars()` when echoing `$cat_name` to prevent XSS.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Why not?

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Are you referring to the fact that it would drop the first line, due to the `fetch()` statement outside of the loop? Myserious comments like "it won't work, find out why yourself." is generally quite unhelpful, at least without a hint to where the author should look.

Answer (score 2):

There are two approach to achieve your desired output.

**Approach One:**

Store `cat_name` in a new array and use it in your HTML or anywhere, where you want to use.

```
<?php
$cat_name = array();
while($categories_list = $cat->fetch()) {
  $cat_name[] = $categories_list['cat_name'];
}
?>

<select name="topic_name">
<?php
foreach ($cat_name as $key => $value) {
?>
  <option value="<?=$value?>" ><?=$value?> </option>
}
?>
</select>
```

**Approach 2:**

```
<?php
while ($categories_list = $cat->fetch()) {
?>
   <option value="<?=$categories_list['cat_name']?>" ><?=$categories_list['cat_name']?> </option>
<?php
}
?>
```

**Whats wrong with your code:**

`$cat_name = $categories_list['cat_name'];` this will only store the last value of your query, you must need to store the value in an array or use `<option>` inside the `while()` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Move the fetch loop to the output section of your code.

So instead of this:

```
echo "<option value=\"".$cat_name."\" >$cat_name </option>";
```

move the loop so it will look like this:

```
While ($categories_list = $cat->fetch()) {
  $cat_name = $categories_list['cat_name'];
  echo "<option value=\"".$cat_name."\" >$cat_name </option>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use while loop while you're outputting the category in select `option`.

Like this,

```
While ($categories_list = $cat->fetch()) {
       echo "<option value=\"".$categories_list['cat_name']."\" >$categories_list['cat_name'] </option>";
}
```